# CyberPower 1500VA shuts off when unplugged?

Tags: power-supply

One of our devs has his workstation plugged into a Cyberpower 1500VA UPS. When he came in this morning, everything was off including the UPS.  When we turned it back on, it showed full capacity.  I am unfamiliar with UPS's in general, but as a test, I unplugged it from the wall. It immediately shut off and so did everything plugged into it (a lamp as a test).  The load was minimal when I performed the "test".

**Is this expected?  Or should I be able to unplug it from the wall and have it continue to supply power?**

This may sound like a dumb question, but I don't know if there is some kind of circuitry that knows the difference between a power outage and unplugging it.  Sorry.

Comment: With none (or very little) load an UPS may show 100% capacity even if the battery is bad. The only way to be sure is do a test with load. You lamp probably wasn't drawing enough power to be enough of a load.

Comment: How old is the UPS?

Comment: Not sure how old the device is, the model is `CP1500AVRLCDa`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its job is to provide an uninterrupted power supply in the event of a power cut - which can eminently be tested by simply unplugging it.

If it doesn't do that, either the battery has failed or the unit itself has failed.
If the battery is more than 3 years old, suspect that first. If not, then send it for repair/replacement.

Comment: Even if it shows full capacity?  Most UPS's I've used have had a test button.  Is there a way to test this one?

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate [How do I run a self-test? | CyberPower](https://www.cyberpowersystems.com/faqs/how-do-i-run-a-self-test/)

Comment: Yes. Unplug it ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try downloading the software and seeing if it provides more info.

Comment: So the INSTANT I click "Run Self Test" in the software the UPS shuts off.  Could that be a battery issue? Doesn't seem like it. Also doesn't appear to be any way to update the firmware on this device.  Not sure how old the device is, the model is `CP1500AVRLCDa`.

Comment: We haven't moved on from "If the battery is more than 3 years... else send the unit for repair". If it powers off, it's broken. You now need to figure out where. You didn't tell us the age of the battery yet.

Comment: I don't know the age of the device or the batteries.  I tried asking them, but they did not answer.

Comment: Either way, you answered my core question, which was "If I unplug it should it keep running".

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate - How old is the unit?  I know from experience that CyberPower puts labels with a date on the unit and/or battery when it was installed.  The `Cyberpower 1500VA` was released several years ago and is not a new product on the market.  This does not mean your unit wasn't new, but you have not specified, when you purchased it.  Have you replaced the battery on the unit?  You don't need  reply to answer these questions, I am telling you, the questions you should be asking the developer (or answering for yourself).  *Please don't reply to this comment I won't respond.*